# Strategy to set the number of initial buckets in `std::unordered_set` in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

If we know that we're going to hash between `m` and `n` items, where `m` and `n` are relatively large, what's a reasonable strategy for setting the number of initial buckets for `std::unordered_set`?  If it helps, in my case `m=n/2`.  In general, I'd like to optimize for speed, but can't afford an unreasonable amount of memory.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How well distributed is the output of your hash function? i.e. how many of the `m` values do you expect to have the same hash code? There's not much benefit to having loads of buckets if the values will all end up in the same ones anyway. But additional buckets don't cost much memory, just an extra pointer per bucket.

Comment: Also, do you really need to care about the initial size? More buckets will get added as needed to keep the load factor below the specified maximum. What are you trying to optimize for, insertion? lookup? removal? There are too many variables to answer your question.

Comment: I'm hashing a collection pointers that are added to the `unorderd_set` one at a time.  Then, I want to query whether or not pointer is in the set.  These are the only two operations and I want them to be fast.

Comment: Then it should be pretty easy to measure and find if there's an optimal initial size. Or just let the library manage the bucket count automatically.

Comment: Well, I could run a bunch of tests, but I'm really interested in some kind of formula for the number of buckets given that I'll have between `m` and `n` elements.  It doesn't have to be optimal, but I would like some insight into the data structure given the setup that I've described.

Comment: There's no such formula. If there was, it would be specific to a single implementation, so not portable.

Comment: Great.  I'm most interested in GCC, but if you're feeling saucy it'd be good to know about Clang's implementation as well.

Comment: Lucky for you the code of both is open source so you can see how they work :-P Also notice that I said "if there was" not "there is, but it's not portable"

Comment: For sure.  Candidly, though, I'm asking on here because I'm hoping that you or perhaps someone else would have some insight into the algorithms and implementations.  Otherwise, every question could be answered with RTFM because it's in some source or some book somewhere.  Nevertheless, thanks for helping me clarify the question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely C++ reference says that constructor (1) set the loading factor to 1.0 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set so, the rehashing should be consistent between implementation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr There's no simple answer. Either measure, or let the container manage the bucket size automatically.

As I tried to say in the comments, there are too many variables, and you don't seem to realise how vague you're being. It took an hour for you to even say which implementation you're interested in.

`m` and `n` are "relatively large" ... relative to what?

"These are the only two operations and I want them to be fast." Define fast? What's fast enough? What's too slow? Have you measured?

If you want to minimize the load factor, so that there is on average no more than one element per bucket (and so no iteration through buckets needed once that the right bucket is known) then you'll need *at least* `n` buckets. But that doesn't guarantee one bucket per element, because the function used to determine the bucket from a hash code might return the same value for every pointer you put in the container. Knowing if that's likely depends on the hash function being used, and the function that maps hash codes to buckets, and the pointer values themselves.

For GCC the hash function for pointers is the identity function. For the default `unordered_map` implementation the mapping to buckets is `hash_function(x) % bucket_count()` and the bucket count is always a prime number, to reduce the likelihood of collisions. If the addresses you're storing in the hash map tend to be separated by multiples of the bucket count then they're going to end up in the same bucket. Knowing how likely that is depends on the number of buckets used for `n` (which you haven't stated) and the distribution of pointer values you're using (which you haven't stated).

If you use a custom hash function that has knowledge of the pointer values you expect to store then you could use a perfect hash function that uniformly distributes between `[0, n)` and then set the `bucket_count()` to `n` and ensure no collisions.

But it's not obvious that ensuring only a single element per bucket is worth it, because it uses more memory. Iterating through a bucket containing two or three elements is not going to be a bottleneck in most programs. Maybe it will be in yours, it's impossible to know because you haven't said what you want except it has to be fast. Which is so vague it's meaningless.

The only way to answer these questions is for you to measure the real world performance, nobody can give you a magic number that will make your code faster based on your vague requirements. **If there was an easy answer that always makes things faster for "relatively large" number of elements then the standard library implementation should already be doing that** and so you'd just be wasting your time doing the same thing by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  One more question to clarify.  On the low end, I'm looking at `n` being on the order of a million.  On the high end, on the order of low billions.  If no initial number of buckets is provided, would you anticipate problems growing the `unordered_set` to this size?

Comment: With sufficient memory available GCC's `unordered_map` will use up to 18446744073709551557ul buckets (or 4294967291ul for 32-bit). I don't know how it performs when actually having to rehash with that many buckets, probably not well! You really need to measure.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you can live with logarithmic performance (usually not a problem), use a std::map instead. Then you have guaranteed lookup complexity 100% of the time, no re-hashing. A very useful property e.g. in hard real-time systems.

Comment: But much slower lookup for large numbers of elements. A sorted vector and `std::binary_search` would be much faster for lookup.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Of course, the chosen data structure depends on the application, vectors are more cache-friendly too. But if you insert a lot, re-sorting the vector may not be practical.